# What is the running time of the following algorithm (in terms of -notation)?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, time-complexity, big-o

Algorithm solves a problem of size  as follows: recursively solves 3 subproblems of size  `- 2`, and then constructs the answer for the original problem in time `(1)`.

It seems obvious that the Master theorem cannot be applied here. So, I thought of drawing a recursion tree, but what bothers me is that do I need to consider two cases: when `n` is odd/even? Or the result sum and hence the running time wouldn't depend on this at all? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: can you solve this if the subproblems are of size n-1? How does it change if the subproblems have size n-2?

Comment: @Henry I suppose that on every new level of tree we need to subtract 2 more from n (T(n-2), T(n-4), T(n-6), etc). And the sum limit changes also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another (possibly simpler) solution in addition to the one proposed by @trincot :

T(n)=3T(n-2)+O(1)=...=3<sup>k</sup>(T(n-2k)+O(1)).

Let's find out the stopping condition for this recurrence relation, i.e. need to find k for which the following holds: n-2k=0 --> k=n/2 --> T(n)=O(3<sup>n/2</sup>)=O(√3<sup>n</sup>)

Answer (score 2):

We'll have to assume that the base case of the recursion occurs when   is either 0 or 1. It could also be that the base case occurs when  is either 1 or 2,  is not allowed to be 0. We don't really know, but it is not that relevant.

In the first case, the number of operations for a given  that is odd, is the same as the number of operations for −1. In the second case it would be the same number of operations as for +1.

So, for determining the asymptotic complexity we can look at just the even numbers (or only the odd numbers).

The recursion tree is a perfect 3-ary tree with a height of (+1)/2 or (+2)/2 (again: depending on the base case).

In a perfect 3-ary tree of height *h*, we have *(3<sup>*h*</sup>-1)/2* nodes, so that is *O(3<sup>*h*</sup>)*, which in terms of  is *O(3<sup>/2</sup>)* = *O((√3))*.

Comment: Still don't exactly understand why we can look at just even or odd numbers (not both of them)

Comment: Asymptotic means looking at the trend for increasing n. Two consecutive n will have same tree size. Then next increases, then equal again. Etc......

Comment: Did this answer your question?